# How would you create a Random String Generator using an instance of another class with parameters?

Tags: java, random, random-seed

Create a Wheel class. The class will simulate spins of the roulette wheel in the range 1-n.
Create a constructor that takes 3 parameters:
   a seed (int)
   a lower bound m (int)
   an upper bound n (int)
Create a method spin() which returns the next random string generated by roll of the wheel. This method should return a string. You can use Random() to generate a number from 0 to (n-1-m) and then add m to get a number in the specified range.
Use Random() to generate a bigInteger (you want large numbers) and then convert it to a String using the toString() method

Current code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Wheel {

    public int seed, m, n;

    public Wheel(int seed, int m, int n) {
        seed = 100000001;

        Random random = new Random(seed);

        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

            System.out.println(100 * random.nextDouble());
        }
    }

    public String spin() {
        seed = 100000001;
        //m = 1;
        //n = 100000001;

        String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        StringBuilder words = new StringBuilder();
        Wheel random = new Wheel(seed, m, n);
        while (words.length() < 10) {
            int index = (int) (random.nextInt() * letters.length());
            words.append(letters.charAt(index));
        }
        String wordMade = words.toString();
        return wordMade;


    }
}
```

Can't seem to get this to work and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand either.  I think you should ask your instructor to clarify the directions.  Roulette wheels don't generate strings, they generate one number per spin.  So I'm pretty confused why you "want big numbers" or what the string is supposed to do.

Comment: I think you're mixin' several tasks, are you?

Comment: Ok, so it turns out it is supposed to generate a numbers continuously and convert the numbers into strings until it finds a number which is between the upper and lower bounds.